# Why Java implements so hard to reading a file

Tags: java

I really don't know, why this is so complex and hard just for reading a file with a lot of classes

- InputStream
- DataInputStream
- InputStream
- BufferReader

What are advantages of below? And what are philosophy at here?

```
private static String fileToString(String filename) throws IOException
{
    InputStream resourceAsStream;
    resourceAsStream        = "".getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    DataInputStream in      = new DataInputStream(resourceAsStream);
    BufferedReader reader   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder builder   = new StringBuilder();
    String line;    
    // For every line in the file, append it to the string builder
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        builder.append(line);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: The `DataInputStream` is completely redundant and can be removed from your sample.

Comment: Why do you use a ClassLoader to get an InputStream from an ordinary File?

Comment: @Bergi Maybe its not an ordinary file. But if it is, yeah, no need for that

Comment: +1: For all of guys tell me that `DataInputStream` is completely redundant and can be removed. But, even if be removed. It is still complex for me.

Comment: Its not a silly question, on the contrary *I* think its an *excellent* question. You are asking why there are multiple tools in the box and what's the use for each of those is. I think thats a methodically excellent approach instead of just asking how to solve the *specific* task at hand.

Comment: @Durandal: Very thanks so much for explain my question.

Comment: It could have been way shorter if you had used a scanner, instead of a reader.  The architects didn't design that code; you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The philosophy is one of flexibility.  Using different types of data streams, you can easily read and write different types of data, like bytes, lines of text, or entire user-defined objects, one at a time to and from I/O sources.

From [The Java Tutorials - I/O Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html):

> An I/O Stream represents an input source or an output destination. A stream can represent many different kinds of sources and destinations, including disk files, devices, other programs, and memory arrays.
>
> Streams support many different kinds of data, including simple bytes, primitive data types, localized characters, and objects. Some streams simply pass on data; others manipulate and transform the data in useful ways.

Start at the lesson trail [Lesson: Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) to get a good overview of Java I/O.

---

If you want to see concrete examples of how to simplify I/O for various data types in Java, I recommend having a look at the [In.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/In.java.html) and [Out.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Out.java.html) classes from Sedgewick & Wayne's [standard libraries](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/).

Answer (score 10):

If you want to read a file for which you have a path, you can even go for this:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/your/file"), charset);
```

Note: Java 7+ required

Comment: Ahh, yes, I suppose you could do that. I've just always preferred to do it the old fashioned way, you know? ;) Doesnt that need java 7 though? << I see your new edit now :)

Comment: Java 7 seems to have some really nice additions. Should have a look at it... :D

Comment: Interesting, I'd never seen this before. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well since you said InputStream twice, it's really only 3 things ;) But it's because there are different things you could store an a file (a serialized object, image, text, etc.), so they all have a common base (InputStream). Then, for basic text, you have a new class, BufferedReader to handle this specific type of storing/reading from/to a file. Lastly, the BufferReader is just there to increase efficiency; you might not want it, so its optional

Also,  Johan Sjöberg is correct, there is no need for the DataInputStream in there, just do:

```
BufferedReader reader   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream));
```

Comment: +1: Thanks so much. But, I don't know why we need to use a lot of classes, in this case.

Comment: Thanks :) But I don't think it's too many still; you could make your own Utilities class (which appears is sort of what you were doing) and have your own methods for reading different things from different files, so you don't gotta type it all out each time

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be hard, checkout [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/):  Here is what reading a file could look like with the simple inclusion of a single jar file:

```
@Cleanup InputStream in = new FileInputStream("File.txt");
byte[] b = new byte[10000];
while (true) {
 int r = in.read(b);
 if (r == -1) break;
}
```

Comment: Yea, you could do that, but A: you should buffer your input stream if possible, and B: using a BufferedReader is just more convenient

Comment: @AlexColeman He is reading into a buffer of ten thousand bytes. *More* buffering won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten the code a bit leaving out the unnecessary `DataInputStream`, and you might use a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) instead:

```
private static String fileToString(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    StringBuilder builder   = new StringBuilder();
    String line;    
    // For every line in the file, append it to the string builder
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        builder.append(line);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I also found the following one-liner at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_entire_file#Java:

```
new Scanner(new File("foo"), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```